# i want to associate links to respective article on dynamically created p element

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, wikipedia-api

[here is my codepen link](https://codepen.io/shubhamshukla1994/pen/YqgLXW)

my html code

```
<div id="main">
  <h1>Wikipedia Viewer</h1>
  <form class="form-inline">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-4 col-lg-7 col-lg-offset-4">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="sr-only" for="search">search</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
          </div>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button></form>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Random">Surprise me!</a>
</div>
<div id="search">
  </search>
```

jquery code for making wikipedia api search call and then displaying title and overview.i want to associate links to respective article on dynamically created p element

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    var article = $("input").val();
    $.ajax({                    //wikipedia api call
      url: "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=search&srsearch=" + article + "&format=json",
      dataType: "jsonp",
      success: function(data) {

        for (var i = 0; i < data.query.search.length; i++) { //displaying titles and snippets accroding to search query. i want to associate link to each dynamically created p element.
          var title = data.query.search[i].title;
          var snippet = data.query.search[i].snippet;
          $("#search").append("<p>" + title + "<br>" + snippet + "</p>");
        }
        $("#main").attr({
          'style': 'display: none'
        });
      },
      error: function() {
        $("h1").html("oops");
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `$("#search").append()` as follows:

```
$("#search")
  .append("<p><a href='https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/" + title + "'>" + title + "</a>" + 
          "<br>" + snippet + "</p>"
         );
```

[**Codepen**](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/aNxvmK)